# Why does Object.prototype.toString.call() give different output than Object.prototype.toString()?

Tags: javascript

Here's something I found in some code I was reading, when I tested in the console:

```
Object.prototype.toString("foo"); // output: "[object Object]"

Object.prototype.toString.call("foo"); // output: "[object String]"
```

I think I may have a faint idea but I can't express in words... can anyone explain?

Comment: Read the docs for [the `call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). The output is different because you're doing drastically different calls. [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) does not take a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two calls are **NOT** equivalent.

The first call:

```
Object.prototype.toString("foo");
```

calls the `toString` method in the context of `Object.prototype`, with an additional `"foo"` parameter (unused), and `Object.prototype` is an `Object`, so the result is `[object Object]`

The second call:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call("foo");
```

calls the `toString` method in the context of `"foo"`, and `Object.prototype.toString` builds an object from it (`new String("foo")`), so the result is `[object String]`

Comment: Actually `"foo"` is a primitive value, only when being [casted to an object](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2) it becomes a `String` instance.

Comment: How would you suggest I reword that? I'm a bit unsure right now.

Comment: Okay, when I call `"foo".toString()`, amd I again calling it in "foo" context? Why is the output different (`"foo"`) in this case?

Comment: Because, in the first case, "foo" is the context, while in the second case it is just a parameter, but the `toString()` method operates only on the context.

Comment: @adityamenon Because `'foo'.toString()` is basically `String.prototype.toString.call('foo')`, since the string primitive is being wrapped in a `String` object.

Comment: Thanks @plalx, it all makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `call` is the object that will be `this` inside the function, not the first parameter of the function:

```
"use strict";
function test(a,b) {
  console.log(this, a, b);
};
var obj = {
  'func' : test
}
test(1,2) // outputs undefined 1 2
test.call(1,2); // outputs 1 2 undefined
obj.func(1,2) // outputs obj 1 2
obj.func.call(1,2) // outputs 1 2 undefined
```